# How to receive data from main process every loop iteration in Electron JS?

Tags: javascript, electron

Good evening! Can you tell me how it is possible to get data from the main process to the render process every iteration in the loop, in order to display the process to the user? Thanks!

**main.js**

```
ipcMain.handle('get-some-backend-data', (event) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    return(i);
  }
});
```

**preload.js**

```
getSomeBackendData: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('get-some-backend-data')
```

**renderer.js**

```
async function handleGetSomeBackendData() {
    try {
      let result = await window.electron.ipcRenderer.getSomeBackendData(
        'get-some-backend-data'
      );
      console.log(result); // i need get (0,1,2), but i have got 0, of course
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to return an array from `ipcMain.handle`, then you should collect the data from each iteration and return the entire array once you're done.

main.js

```js
ipcMain.handle('get-some-backend-data', (event) => {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result.push(i);
  }

  return result;
});
```

renderer.js

```js
async function handleGetSomeBackendData() {
  try {
    let result = await window.electron.ipcRenderer.getSomeBackendData(
      'get-some-backend-data'
    );
    console.log(result); // should now log [0, 1, 2]
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

If this is not what you want, you need to share more of your `ipcMain` handler code to show what you are doing inside that loop.

To elaborate on the problem: This is not specific to Electron. If you return from inside a loop in any regular JS function, the entire function will return with the argument to the `return` statement and then be completed (the same holds for most other mainstream languages).

That being said, JavaScript supports suspending function execution, optionally returning a result, with the ability to pick up execution later (and possibly return another result). This is done using generator functions, see [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).
However, they are quite specific and usually not what you want or need.